# React.js Re-rendering issue with multiple panels/Tables

Tags: reactjs

We have page in react that renders 5 tables. Our requirement is to refresh a single table in case we do some activity on the table such as seleting some row and making a POST call.

The problem is that we are not able to refresh a paritcular table (as it possible in normal secenarios using a ajax call).

All the tables are rendered using single render method and hence we have to render the whole page in case we change or accesss even a single table.
Is there any option in `Reactjs` to refresh only a part of a page that rendered ?

Answer (score 0):

The way to have only a single component re-render is to give it state. E.g:

- upon initial load (component rendered by parent component) it sets state as loading
- give component listener to a ajax results table or something similar
- onChange of ajax-results-table: update state using `this.setState()`

Then only the component re-renders.

NB: React is really smart and superfast about actual re-renders. Common practice is to re-render the entire page. React figures out which parts/ components have changed, and only updates changed components.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing you data to each table in props ?
Could you split each table into a separate component , I am unsure why you need to render five tables in one view as you describe.  Then the opportunity arises to use PureRenderMixin (shouldComponentupdate) , https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html.

Comment: We already have separate table component and we are just passing different props to display the data via  the single render. Would you please suggest for this.